# When creating a Panel Page and selecting a layout, the page layout is not overidden

Tags: panels, theming

I'm using *Omega* theme and have built 4 custom layouts for my sub-theme. If I activate layouts and select one in the admin my *Omega* sub-theme, everything is fine.

Now I want to use those layouts as the base for a *Panel Page*. When I do that, it injects the layout into the content section of the main (default) `.tpl` theme file.

My expectation is that it will completely replace that theme file the same way it does if I activate and use the layout in my sub-theme admin.

I've made sure to check disable *Drupal* `blocks/regions` when starting to build the layout.

I even tried using the stock layouts that come with *Omega* and no luck.

I can't think of anything else to try, especially since the layouts work outside of *Panels*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how Panels is designed to work.  It can only take over the content rendered to the main content region.  If you want Panels to take over all regions then you need to use [Panels Everywhere](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere) which is, incidentally, compatible with Omega 4.

Comment: Ok. Interesting. I'll check out [Panels Everywhere](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere). It seems like a Panel Page would be useless then without that. Could you help me understand a use case for a Panel Page then if it just injects into the content area?

Comment: It's actually very useful!  A common pattern with Panels is to set up your theme with a few simple regions (header, footer, maybe sidebar) then have Panels responsible for all other page layout by injecting the appropriate layout into the content region.  Your experience with Omega is probably confusing you because it, more than any other theme I know, attempts to provide functionality that does overlap with Panels a bit.  The problem with theme regions is that they're global.  Panels lets you set up complex layouts without polluting the global region space.

Comment: @ErikHanson Also: Page Manager/Panels is, IMO, by far the best, most flexible way to embed content in a Drupal page.